# How can I make it so that when I click on a word in the text_area window with the mouse button, it will display the options below it?

Tags: select, textarea, streamlit

I need to make a suggestion for the correct spelling of a word when you click on it. I track if a word is spelled incorrectly and I need to add an option to click on the word in the text_area so that a menu for selecting its correct variants appears under it. Is there an example in the documentation or a plugin to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality isn't natively supported by Streamlit. There are a few related custom components ([streamlit-modal](https://pypi.org/project/streamlit-modal/) / [st-pop-up-component](https://pypi.org/project/st-pop-up-component)), but it doesn't seem like they would fulfill the exact use case you're looking for (since you're looking for the modal to appear right above the clicked text). Your best bet in this case would likely be to [build a custom component](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/components/create).